# Dojo JSON call back always returns an error

Tags: java, javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo and making an AJAX call to a JAVA Class and trying to get the output of the program to an Alert box to the client.

```
var showResult = function(result){
    console.log("Showing Result()");
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: result});
    console.dir(store);
            
    store.fetch( { onItem: function(data) {  alert("Hie"); },
        onError: function(error,request){ alert("ERROR");}
    });

};
```

This is my code, `showResult` basically is call back function from `xhr` request. I can see `console.dir(store)` printed onto Firebug but the fetch function always returns the `onError` block.

My store array is of the form `{info="Test Message"}` and I need to retrieve "Test Message" and display it in an Alert box. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If the `result` is just an array, you should use `new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data : {items : result}})` to create the store.

For example, `result` is `[{info : "Test Message 1"}, {info : "Test Message 2"}]`, then the code should be:

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data : {items : result}});
store.fetch({
    onItem : function(item) {
        alert(store.getValue(item, "info"));
    },
    onError : function(error) {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructor suggestion. It does seem perfect! 

Although, I still get "Error! alert boxes. So, the onError is getting executed! Any ideas?

Comment: I think the reason is that you have JavaScript error in the onItem handler, which triggers the onError handler. Use simple logic in onItem first to make sure the store is created correctly. Then debug your onItem handler to find the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
store.fetch({query: {info: '*'}},
    onItem: function(data) {
        alert("Hie");
    },
    onError: function(error, request) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
);
```

as well you may want to see if `onComplete: function(items){console.log(items);}` works instead of `onItem`, it is worth a try.

As well `console.log` your error so that you can see what the issue is.

A few other things do you store have an identifier and label set?